# The Directory.Exists() static method (somehow) removes my Static Dictionary's items in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, azure-functions

**See Edit below for the possible culprit**
I encountered a weird interaction today, and I cannot make any sense of it.

Somehow my static Dictionary is wiped at the end of my endpoint's function.

 It seems to exclusively happen in conjunction with the `Directory` static class methods.

 **The goal of this question is to see if others can replicate this issue and if there is a logical explanation for this behavior.**

## The setup

I have a local Azure function with two endpoints in a class: `/start` and `/stop`

 I Also have a Class with a static dictionary

```
public class State{
    public static Dictionary<string,string> TestValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

I add a value to the Dictionary with `/start`.

 I then access and return the value with `/stop`.

### Correct flow

This is the /start endpoint

```
        public static async Task<IActionResult> startTraining(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "training/{trainingId}/start")] HttpRequest req,
            string trainingId,
            ILogger log)
        {  
            string newFolderPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + $"/Training-{trainingId}";

            State.TestValues.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
            return new OkObjectResult("Added a word");
            if (!Directory.Exists(newFolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolderPath);
            }
        }
```

Then the result if I call `/stop`

```
        public static async Task<IActionResult> stopTraining(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "training/{trainingId}/stop")] HttpRequest req,
            string trainingId,
            ILogger log)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(State.TestValues["MyKey"]);
        }
```

Correctly returns: `MyValue`. I never go to the Directory.Exists()

### The unexpected behavior

If I do reach `Directory.Exists()` and then add `MyValue` to the Dictionary.

```
        public static async Task<IActionResult> startTraining(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "training/{trainingId}/start")] HttpRequest req,
            string trainingId,
            ILogger log)
        {  
            string newFolderPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + $"/Training-{trainingId}";

            if (!Directory.Exists(newFolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolderPath);
            }
            State.TestValues.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
            return new OkObjectResult("Added a word");
        }
```

Calling `/stop` no longer yields `MyValue`. Instead it yields

```
System.Private.CoreLib: The given key 'MyKey' was not present in the dictionary.
```

I'm kinda baffled and hope there is a clear explanation to this behavior.

I am by no means a C# expert but I cannot fathom how the Directory method affects the Dictionary. 
The only similarity they have is that they are both Static

## Edit

The problem was that I used `Directory.CreateDirectory` to create a directory in the `bin/output/` directory. Creating it elsewhere did not wipe the Dictionary items. 
But I still don't know **why** it causes this behavior. So I will leave this question open.

Comment: In the second instance, is the action actually creating the folder and returning the expected result? Is it possible that `CreateDirectory` is throwing an exception?

Comment: @jmcilhinney CreateDirectory throws no exception and creates the folder successfully.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But now that I run it again, if the Directory does exists, the dictionary value does not disappear, so Directory.CreateDirectory() is the culprit? It creates the folder in the build's output folder, could that cause issues?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh it really seems to be the fact that the directory is created in the `bin/output` directory. 
If I create it anywhere else, the Dictionary is not wiped. 
Do you happen to know why this happens?

Comment: I'm stumped. Does this only happen when debugging? Can you run it without debugging and see whether the same behaviour is exhibited.

Comment: @jmcilhinney nope, not debugging (c# with VScodium on linux heheh), I'm just running the azure-function locally. 
Would you be able to reproduce the setup based on the question's description? I like to believe this is all due to some mis-configuration on my end. But I won't know until someone has time to try it out on their end.

Comment: Probably changes to `bin` folder (creating new directory there) triggers reinitializing of the application, like hot-reload. No other explanation. Also, if it is dynamic function then it will be evicted if not called for sometime.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot the hot reload is most likely the case, but I had hoped there to be some documentation around this somewhere. But I couldn't find any so I can't verify that being the case